# Aptana and Compass on Windows 8

Tags: ruby, sass, aptana, compass-sass

I'm attempting to set up my development environment on a new Windows 8 laptop. I installed Aptana, then Ruby 1.9.3 and pulled my source in from git. I then ran gem install compass and tested by creating a new project with compass (all of which worked fine). I then opened my project in aptana and typed in compass watch and am given a `sh.exe: compass: command not found` error in terminal. I'm not sure why compass is not able to compile in my project folder.

Folder set up is as follows:

- Project: C:/Users/username/repos/project-name
- Ruby: C:/Users/username/Ruby193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's not finding the gems in your PATH. Have you tried launching Aptana from the command line? If you don't want to use the command line, make sure that your login PATH is setup correctly.

From [the docs](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/getting_started):

> You should also make sure that your login PATH is set up correctly
>   such that you can execute the ruby, gem, rails, and git commands
>   correctly. Setting these things up in your .bashrc (or equivalent)
>   isn't sufficient, because it doesn't get evaluated by default when GUI
>   applications like Aptana Studio 3 get launched.
>
> Ruby switching utilities like rvm should also work, provided that you
>   set them up in your login PATH as well.
>
> If getting your login PATH set up in this way isn't practical for you,
>   you can work around the problem by launching Aptana Studio 3 from the
>   command line, using the studio3 command line utility. This utility can
>   be found at the top level of the Aptana Studio 3 installation folder,
>   so you can put that folder in your PATH for convenience. (The command
>   line utility can also be called after Aptana Studio 3 is running, to
>   get it to open source code files for editing.)